# Get correct method through reflection when parameters only differ in generic type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

`System.Linq.Queryable` has 2 `Where` Methods that differ sligtly:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, int, bool>> predicate);
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate);
```

I need to select the seconds one with the `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>` parameter.

I tried so far:

```
typeof(Queryable).GetTypeInfo()
.GetMethod(nameof(Queryable.Where), new [] { typeof(IQueryable<object>), typeof(Expression<Func<object,bool>>) })
// results in null

typeof(Queryable).GetTypeInfo()
.GetMethod(nameof(Queryable.Where), new [] { typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<Func<,>>) })
// Error: Unexpected use of an unbound generic name

typeof(Queryable).GetTypeInfo()
.GetMethod(nameof(Queryable.Where), new [] { typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<Func<,>>) })
// Exception: Ambiguous match found
```

What do I have to specify to get the second method without using `GetMethods()` and relying on it being the second one.

Comment: Does this part compile at all? `typeof(Expression<Func<,>>)` Here this gives me "Unexpected use of an unbound generic name".

Comment: If you can construct `Type` objects for the parameters then you can use `GetMethod` but I doubt you will be able to construct them using `TSource` as part of the `Type`.

Comment: Note that you cannot use open generic arguments like this, you have to close them even if you close them with the type parameter, this method `public void Method<T>(List<T> list) { }` cannot be found by this code: `typeof(Test).GetTypeInfo().GetMethod(nameof(Test.Method), new[] { typeof(List<>) })`, you have to have the `T` in there.

Comment: You can verify my second comment by actually using `.GetMethods()`, grabbing the right method, extracting the `ParameterType` of its parameters, then passing them back through a call to `.GetMethod(...)`. This will return the right method back to you. However, I don't think you can easily construct those `Type` values in the first place.

Comment: I personally find solving such task much easier by using prototype expressions. But since you seem to ask for reflection only solution, the question is a dupe.